# how to change particular date background using drawable resource file in android date picker

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

[image]

For example, in this image 17th different background and 26th different background.

Expecting showing differentiation normal days and important days

Comment: have you done something? please share a code snippet that you've done

Comment: i don't have any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not straitforward at all. To change the background of a specific day, you have to get access to the `MonthAdaptor`.
So at first you have to create the `DatePickerDialog`.

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
    this,
    R.style.MyDatePickerDialogTheme,
    null,
    year, month, day);
```

Then you have to get the get the `datePicker` of `DatePickerDialog`.

```
DatePicker datePicker = datePickerDialog.getDatePicker();
```

Now you need to get access to the view of the `DatePicker`.

```
CalendarView calendarView = datePicker.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/calendar_view", null, null));
```

To modify the view you need to get its adaptor. You can check other methods of `CalenderView` in [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView)

```
DayPickerPagerAdapter dayPickerPagerAdapter = (DayPickerPagerAdapter) calendarView.getAdapter();
```

Now get the `MonthAdaptor`

```
MonthAdapter monthAdapter = dayPickerPagerAdapter.createMonthAdapter((Month) dayPickerPagerAdapter.getPage(0));
```

Finally from the `MonthAdaptor` you can get any day of month using `getItem` and its index and set its appearance. ([Check here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView#setDateTextAppearance(int)))

```
MonthAdapter.CalendarDay calendarDay = monthAdapter.getItem(16);

calendarView.setDateTextAppearance(calendarDay, R.style.MyCustomDayStyle);
```

Finally show your dialog.

```
datePickerDialog.show();
```

I hope it works.

**EDIT:**

Don't forget to add your custom style into `style.xml` file.

```
<style name="MyCustomDayStyle">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_background</item>
</style>
```